# Can you filter specific prefixes from a redistributed EIGRP summary route?

Tags: eigrp, redistribution

Say I have an EIGRP router advertising the summary address 192.168.128.0/22 and on a connected router I'm redistributing EIGRP routes into OSPF.

Is there any way for me to only redistribute 192.168.128.0/24 and 192.168.129.0/24 instead of the entire /22 prefix? I tried using a route map to only permit 128 and 129

```
route-map EIGRPDIST permit 10
 match ip address EIGRPDISTMAP
ip access-list standard EIGRPDISTMAP
 permit 192.168.128.0 0.0.1.255
```

but the connected router still advertises the entire /22 into OSPF.

I could obviously advertise the networks individually and filter from there but I specifically would like to filter the summary address.

Comment: The `/22` network is what is in the EIGRP database, so that is what gets redistributed. You cannot redistribute networks not in the database.

Comment: That's what I thought, just figured I'd ask. You never know. Thanks